# How to extract responseText from ajax error response?

Tags: jquery, ajax, go, httphandler

In my go http handler function response to ajax request, I'd like to send an error message like this:

```
func AddBlogPOST(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  //process request
  if everythingIsOk(r) {
      w.Write([]byte("ok"))
      return
   } else { 
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
    w.Write([]byte("not enough credit"))
    return  
}
```

The ajax request is like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function (e) { 
   $.ajax({
    url: '/blog/',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('.form').serialize(),
    success: (res) => {
      console.log('success body:', res);
        console.log(res);
       },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log('an error occured:', err);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

It works fine when the reuqest is successful and I get `success body: ok` in the browser console. However when there is an error, I get an object like:

```
readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort: ƒ (e)
always: ƒ ()
catch: ƒ (e)
done: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
getResponseHeader: ƒ (e)
overrideMimeType: ƒ (e)
pipe: ƒ ()
progress: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ (e)
readyState: 4
responseText: "credit not enough"
setRequestHeader: ƒ (e,t)
state: ƒ ()
status: 401
statusCode: ƒ (e)
statusText: "Unauthorized"
then: ƒ (t,n,r)
```

How can I extract `"credit not enough"` from this object?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting `undefined` in the error handler as the first argument (which you've named `err`) is actually the jqXHR object, which should never be null/empty/undefined. *Edit* - unless the `$.ajax()` call is causing an error before it's being sent perhaps. Check the other arguments that `error` provides to give you more useful information to debug.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You are right. I was mistakenly tried to print out `err.data`. But now that I have `err` alone, I get a large error object without the error message. Please check my updated question.

Comment: Looks like your error message is here: `responseText: "credit not enough"`. Bear in mind that the `error` handler doesn't parse the `responseText` for you automatically as the `success` handler does.

Comment: Right, Please see my updated question. Still have difficulty extracting the error message.

Comment: `err.responseText`

Comment: Thank you sir. My stupid quesiton. Answer if you like and I'll accept.

Comment: Check the ajax docs and you will see what you think is `err` is actually the xhr object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument named `err` in your `error` handler is the jqXHR object. To retrieve the error message you return from your server side code you need to access the `responseText` property of that object manually. Try this:

```
error: (jqXHR) => {
  console.log('an error occurred:', jqXHR.responseText);
}
```